powershell script for windows schedule task
`Is this the most efficient way of getting informations about the schedule tasks?
$remoteComputer = "MyRemoteComputer"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteComputer -ScriptBlock {
# Get scheduled tasks
$tasks = Get-ScheduledTask | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo
# Combine task information with the task path
$tasksWithPath = Get-ScheduledTask | Select-Object TaskName, TaskPath, @{Name="State";Expression={(Get-ScheduledTaskInfo -TaskName $_.TaskName).State}}, @{Name="LastRunTime";Expression={(Get-ScheduledTaskInfo -TaskName $_.TaskName).LastRunTime}}, @{Name="NextRunTime";Expression={(Get-ScheduledTaskInfo -TaskName $_.TaskName).NextRunTime}}, @{Name="LastResult";Expression={(Get-ScheduledTaskInfo -TaskName $_.TaskName).LastResult}}

# Format and display the results
$tasksWithPath | Format-Table -Property TaskPath, TaskName, State, LastRunTime, NextRunTime, LastResult -AutoSize`your text`

} -Credential (Get-Credential)
i was trying it this way and it works but I wanna know if there is an easier way of getting the infos

Please edit your question and explain why you think your method is not "easy" or "efficient". Exactly what criteria are we using to determine what is "easy" or "efficient" and what is not?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There is no easier way but better way:
$remoteComputer = "RemoteComputerName"  

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteComputer -ScriptBlock {
    
    $tasks = Get-ScheduledTask | ForEach-Object {
        try {
            $taskInfo = Get-ScheduledTaskInfo -TaskName $_.TaskName -TaskPath $_.TaskPath
            $state = if ($taskInfo.State -eq $null -or $taskInfo.State -eq "") { "Unknown" } else { $taskInfo.State }

            [PSCustomObject]@{
                TaskPath    = $_.TaskPath
                TaskName    = $_.TaskName
                State       = $state
                LastRunTime = $taskInfo.LastRunTime
                NextRunTime = $taskInfo.NextRunTime
                LastResult  = $taskInfo.LastTaskResult
            }
        } catch {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                TaskPath    = $_.TaskPath
                TaskName    = $_.TaskName
                State       = "N/A"
                LastRunTime = "N/A"
                NextRunTime = "N/A"
                LastResult  = "N/A"
            }
        }
    }

    $tasks | Format-Table -AutoSize
} -Credential (Get-Credential)  


by removing redundent Get-ScheduledTaskInfo call for one task, error handling and handling of unknown state or empty state.
